# Вынос логики работы в отдельный класс

Tags: java

Хочу вынести логику из `Main` в отдельный класс, но не получается.
Создал папку "logic" и хочу, чтобы логика была там, а `Main` чтобы только выполнял.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        TaxiStation station = new TaxiStation("D:\\Cars.csv");
        List<Car> carPool = station.getCarPool();
        //Посчитать стоимость автопарка.
        double poolPrice = 0.0;
        for (Car car : carPool) {
            poolPrice += car.getPrice();
        }
        System.out.println("Cost of taxistation's cars: " + poolPrice );
        //Провести сортировку автомобилей парка по расходу топлива.
        Collections.sort(carPool, new Comparator<Car>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Car car1, Car car2) {
                return ((int) Math.round(100.0 * (car1.getFuelConsumption() - car2.getFuelConsumption())));
            }
        });
        for (Car car: carPool) {
            System.out.printf("FuelConsumption of %s: %s", car, car.getFuelConsumption());
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Как это всё записать в классе `logic`, оставить только `main`?

Comment: Ну точно также, как вы вынесли класс `TaxiStation` куда-то также и logic выносите,а в main делаете `new logic`.... грубо говоря......или там какой-либо класс со статическими методами, если оно не привязано к экземпляру

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала создаем логику, в классе логики я создал два метода, статический и обычный, на самом деле достаточно одного, так что выбрать нужный:

```
public class Logic {
    //статический метод (если не нужно создавать екземпляр класса)
    public static void logicStatic() throws IOException {
        TaxiStation station = new TaxiStation("D:\\Cars.csv");
        List<Car> carPool = station.getCarPool();
        //Посчитать стоимость автопарка.
        double poolPrice = 0.0;
        for (Car car : carPool) {
            poolPrice += car.getPrice();
        }
        System.out.println("Cost of taxistation's cars: " + poolPrice );
        //Провести сортировку автомобилей парка по расходу топлива.
        Collections.sort(carPool, new Comparator<Car>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Car car1, Car car2) {
                return ((int) Math.round(100.0 * (car1.getFuelConsumption() - car2.getFuelConsumption())));
            }
        });
        for (Car car: carPool) {
            System.out.printf("FuelConsumption of %s: %s", car, car.getFuelConsumption());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    //обычный метод (если создается экземпляр класса логики)
    public void logic() throws IOException {
        TaxiStation station = new TaxiStation("D:\\Cars.csv");
        List<Car> carPool = station.getCarPool();
        //Посчитать стоимость автопарка.
        double poolPrice = 0.0;
        for (Car car : carPool) {
            poolPrice += car.getPrice();
        }
        System.out.println("Cost of taxistation's cars: " + poolPrice );
        //Провести сортировку автомобилей парка по расходу топлива.
        Collections.sort(carPool, new Comparator<Car>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Car car1, Car car2) {
                return ((int) Math.round(100.0 * (car1.getFuelConsumption() - car2.getFuelConsumption())));
            }
        });
        for (Car car: carPool) {
            System.out.printf("FuelConsumption of %s: %s", car, car.getFuelConsumption());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Потом в основном классе вызываем нужный метод логики (статический или обычный):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        //Если не нужно создавать экземпляр класса тогда:
        Logic.logicStatic();
        //Если нужно создать екземпляр класса тогда:
        Logic lgk = new Logic();
        lgk.logic();
        //если необходимо, можно изменить методы для того
        //чтобы им можно было передавать аргументы
        //например:
        //Logic.logicStatic("Some Car");
    }
}
```